# Уменьшение картинки

Tags: javascript

помогите решить проблему. Есть код по увеличению(при нажатии) картинки и уменьшение(при уходе с нее). При увеличении все работает корректно, а при уменьшении ничего не работает.

```js
function increase(event){
    event.currentTarget.style.width = event.currentTarget.style.width + '300px';
}

function decrease(event){
    event.currentTarget.style.width = event.currentTarget.style.width - '300px';
}
```

```css
.stylediv{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseout='decrease(event)' onclick='increase(event)'  class="stylediv" > Контент </div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь присвоить к  `width + '300px'` **(строка).** Когда к пустой строке присваиваются строка `'300px'`, вы получаете именно этот результат.

**Дальше вы пытаетесь** отнять > `width - '300px`. Вот только ваш width  уже строка - `'300px'`
[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/j0d5kpfe/1/).

**Обратите внимания** - `style.width` изначально пустая строка, при этом в css  вы явно указали это свойство в размере 100px

Comment: Спасибо, за пояснение)

Answer (score 0):

Когда что-то не получается в JS, то ваш первый друг - команда `console.log`. Добавив её в функции мы увидим, что `event.currentTarget.style.width` это строка, причём пустая в первый раз. Соответственно `+` у нас срабатывает, а `-` уже нет.

**Решение 1. Просто вводить нужный размер фиксировано.**

```js
function increase(event){
    console.log(event.currentTarget.style.width);
    event.currentTarget.style.width = '400px';
}

function decrease(event){
    console.log(event.currentTarget.style.width);
    event.currentTarget.style.width = '100px';
}
```

```css
.stylediv{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseout='decrease(event)' onclick='increase(event)'  class="stylediv" > Контент </div>
```

**Решение 2. Воспользоваться css переменной и менять её.**

```js
const r = document.querySelector(':root');

function increase(event){
    r.style.setProperty('--add-size', '300px');
}

function decrease(event){
    r.style.setProperty('--add-size', '0px');
}
```

```css
:root {
  --size: 100px;
  --add-size: 0px;
}
.stylediv{
  background-color: red;
  width: calc(var(--size) + var(--add-size));
  height: 100px;
  transition: width .25s linear;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseout='decrease(event)' onclick='increase(event)'  class="stylediv" > Контент </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)